# Access Denied using python requests and headers

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Im trying to get information from [www.aldi.co.uk](http://www.aldi.co.uk) but I keep getting access denied with python requests even when using headers from the website. An example URL i was trying to webscrape is https://www.aldi.co.uk/gardenline-2000w-patio-heater/p/709938458399000

```
with open('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/proxies2.txt') as f:
    PROXIES = f.readlines()

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.aldi.co.uk',
    'method': 'GET',
    'path': '/gardenline-2000w-patio-heater/p/709938458399000',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'cookie': 'JSESSIONID=3CD7A9CD1F847495BC0E57269B0D2343.node5; mercia_pers=15dbd719637e71e60e064d3064d298c0da86611e; b1pi=!dVpaE+0OdClIJlDBIJDu7YLsLa10Fj5VXK60G1v10AEXoRwO7BVS0C6sZ++KgnjRJbFDk6WX6K7CyFk=; bm_sz=566521EFC53AE332524BF8A3685DB4D9~YAAQVeQWAqyBfjJ5AQAAL2fQgwsVeG8vZbdoiSjRseh3EQtmAw+s7t2wc1idrKIP54BG7+4BbyOwnSGfVjYswRgGvbJR1Ab/rd1KK6d2089qTkRwbdo7ualo72Tb1MxS9eBFUsAQZLADc8LQwh9Lf0mOEDuTWLHG3WPL/tWpRWs7zIGzgBTJSjAGklW2xqs0; _gcl_au=1.1.1711508455.1621414143; px_random=1; ak_bmsc=12D85371C2578A6C86F8010A7775C3140216E455B2060000FFD0A460101E7146~plUnE+Y3O3qH92wWP4RKrOIZ75DoHXQ782drrSUjzA4AFxFqAGGda2Q71kZW9MKLQMSIPGSy0b2mER3KKFFFJCHHvEPi85myXeUMExqzJz9yhP3zGkG+yk1RwjkT0Bxi5Gu0uU7gK5zjOLtCByAVki9oDM0z5gYpK0StNP19EzZvhIUtqShvNxagYxKA3ZR+FSH1ZfVkSTQPDIaoDS1NfLa3Xw0iG+IaoFcg0SapH40Mr1Gze7DNJseRJjZk6uHrLH; AMCVS_95446750574EBBDF7F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; _hjTLDTest=1; _hjid=dd61e5d7-6420-4751-a6ff-531345b775d0; _hjFirstSeen=1; bm_sv=5FDE1A04B76A59BDA13506B03EE1A388~qH6bHmkgTSXHJmnMknd6rz+apNw7QYxO2a9vKPYbdPuFIt01M//OXvb515o0Rn6O/7cXh077yUtYAfjKTWxZZ28IxChyTlWif08M+gm/qTtK+tfcJ1ElbKOvqPDL7V1Z5F6PmS6HyXCJ1lmmddlMLkdJkFk62zjwJ06vKlscb4M=; _uetsid=10915620b87f11eba4782bddfe4be808; _uetvid=1091af00b87f11eba4af25f4003c61bd; _ga=GA1.3.514717246.1621414144; _gid=GA1.3.862108792.1621414144; AMCV_95446750574EBBDF7F000101%40AdobeOrg=-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C18767%7CMCMID%7C16739144063247909584513939200244025078%7CMCAAMLH-1622018944%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1622018944%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1621421344s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.2.0; BVBRANDID=90e17435-7edf-450f-81ae-9acc5e07a709; BVBRANDSID=879c4208-412b-44a8-92e9-bbf6a9466c97; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=0; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; rr_rcs=eF5j4cotK8lMETA0NzTRNdQ1ZClN9kgztQTyElN1jVMNLXRNjJMtdFNTDIHcJNMU81RLIzMjM0sAlEoOSA; _dc_gtm_UA-62398555-4=1; _fbp=fb.2.1621414145210.1275760171; _derived_epik=dj0yJnU9OENZUUdzMk1kamt3c3M4WE5RRi0zSUtTaGVUdTNZX2Ymbj11ek1sUVhLSjJWVzA1NUs5UmdPYUF3Jm09NyZ0PUFBQUFBR0NrMFFNJnJtPWUmcnQ9QUFBQUFHQVVnWlE; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU5UZGpPV1pqTVRZdE1UTTRZaTAwT0RCaExUbGhZekl0WkdVMFl6SmxOR1ZsT1RNeg; BVImplmercia=11002_5_0; _abck=25BD5B1352FF94A494F37B1D0F75572D~0~YAAQVeQWArOBfjJ5AQAAEHjQgwVlotJa2ibNkcfJoxy8PuZj3f2IXG1tblii4YK+jK7Ns5M5J+EYKse7lrnG5bgsD5p+5RPVpWDfpgKfBLJPBiFKNgxWnwXRFgUVsAYWkntTM/TxPR3NQWZuUOG0M3hjwHxN/x3E3HZoEqDmgoDO5R/l6boWjeh2s0Vp5hFX8pVaUGIHy+2vK/TN9HmYt+zn1+5JHZ1qb9+6/LGGRfh3CIiPO1PJ23lwdNCJTRZwc39jtzqiL412q4KNuOIowO0cgyayckmCOilyqRHjK6+OGgEblY/c1PakRF/5bmkTLvxAR4NzELDyscOLb8SdBeCM2jK78IiOVnpSeQScpVbOYUENP9pc5+hYFm9HBhAy3cQQDTJ50NKH6d69uDEFcA+m7f9XUbi0~-1~||-1||~-1; QueueITAccepted-SDFrts345E-V3_easter2021=EventId%3Deaster2021%26QueueId%3D00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%26RedirectType%3Ddisabled%26IssueTime%3D1621414148%26Hash%3D9a60f4e686dd39c4e97a68193d55b3bf6dca90c5d4d417d20ddd3ed6992296c1; _taggstar_ses=11aa20f2-b87f-11eb-896f-9958026d8250; _taggstar_vid=11aa20f2-b87f-11eb-896f-9958026d8250; _taggstar_exp=v:3|id:|group:; s_vnum=1652950147659%26vn%3D1; s_invisit=true; s_nr=1621414149284-New; gpv_pn=%2Fketer-manor-garden-shed%2Fp%2F710498460844800; s_cc=true; __atuvc=1%7C20; __atuvs=60a4d0ffec2acf52000; aam_uuid=17038672222160981164484197334904414492',
    'origin': 'www.aldi.co.uk',
    'referer': 'www.aldi.co.uk/',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
}
    
proxy_index=random.randint(0,len(PROXIES)-1)
proxy_parts=PROXIES[proxy_index].split(':')
proxy_parts[3]=proxy_parts[3].strip('\n')
proxy_parts[3]=proxy_parts[3].strip(' ')

            
            
proxy={"http":('http://'+proxy_parts[2]+':'+proxy_parts[3]+'@'+proxy_parts[0]+':'+proxy_parts[1]),"https":('http://'+proxy_parts[2]+':'+proxy_parts[3]+'@'+proxy_parts[0]+':'+proxy_parts[1])}

html = scraper.get(info[0], proxies= proxy, headers=headers).text

print(html)
```

I thought it may've been a proxy issue but I still get the same error running it without proxies. This is what the html returns:

```
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <script defer src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderRecaptchas&render=explicit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="ab27d842a4c159f0791de7fc7d0e9e7a">var _cf = _cf || [];  _cf.push(['_setFsp', true]);  _cf.push(['_setBm', true]);  _cf.push(['_setAu', '/staticweb/4a5ae10f5cfti2055070e1c94cd9e821b']); </script><script type="text/javascript" nonce="ab27d842a4c159f0791de7fc7d0e9e7a" src="/staticweb/4a5ae10f5cfti2055070e1c94cd9e821b"></script></body>
<!--Variable required in redirect.tag in order to ASM to work -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ACC = { config: {} };
    ACC.config.encodedContextPath = "";
</script>
</html>
<div class="hidden">
        vdecKVlCbUukcVtbDymMUYPJVVOTSBpMLSEKMcLEeBAJDpdpodOhdpAywCtFBYmbtPMYYwiLlhFSXjpVUjccPKKFupuVFArBvjLmVZlJbIttTIPLutuodUqhEtjYmUwVRkqMiHlSkkBjnjQhiyBcJYkbuybVNRUTrqfQYjGNdoS
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <script defer src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderRecaptchas&render=explicit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="cdaad728d6c7629abcaf0b22503c1f0f">var _cf = _cf || [];  _cf.push(['_setFsp', true]);  _cf.push(['_setBm', true]);  _cf.push(['_setAu', '/staticweb/4a5ae10f5cfti2055070e1c94cd9e821b']); </script><script type="text/javascript" nonce="cdaad728d6c7629abcaf0b22503c1f0f" src="/staticweb/4a5ae10f5cfti2055070e1c94cd9e821b"></script></body>
<!--Variable required in redirect.tag in order to ASM to work -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ACC = { config: {} };
    ACC.config.encodedContextPath = "";
</script>
</html>
<div class="hidden">
        QNBuxaDGYAfWXfkAiKIJFmGHySjFArtIZPjyUmiqetXcgYSrMvtvOYUcazdZFnGWEDDYNsJplgFXjofUdqXnnAAtClJlpcikRbNQlldVEKUWNSFIdwgNRZKcWkNkLUAYCyWUpqsIfotcXDnfOdHJnWTZTTaKXdGoWYswgnCNNRzwnHbLBuiUQMkEbrhmrxx
</div>
```

Is there anything else I can add to the request to stop the website denying the request? If not and selenium is the only option is there a way to run it at a similar speed to requests

Comment: every request may need new fresh cookies and using cookies from browser may not work. Especially if you use the same cookies with different PROXIES. Normal human can't use the same cookies with different PROXIES - so it is easy to recognize bot/script.

Comment: if page uses `JavaScript` then it can recognize bot/script which doesn't use `JavaScript`.

Comment: I get access denied even for https://www.aldi.co.uk/ in browser. It may check something more (ie.  IP to detect country) or server has problem at this moment and I would have to wait until admins fix it.